# Rails remote form works for one model, does not for another

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, rubygems

I have a few models in my application. For all of them there is no problem to send form with :remote => true.

But there is a problem with one called Banners. It is placed in separated gem, but when I moved its model and controller to application, it still doesn't work.

This code has no effect. In chrome network inspector there is always pending status for this request. It does not put logs in rails server etc.

```
= form_for [:admin, Banner.last], :remote => true do |f|
 = f.text_field :name
 %button{:type=>'submit'} send banner
```

This one works perfectly.

```
= form_for [:admin, Company.last], :remote => true do |f|
 = f.text_field :name
 %button{:type=>'submit'} send company
```

Routes:

```
resources :banners
resources :companies
```

Controllers are simple and similar.

When I remove :remote => true from banner form, it works.

Gemfile in my banners gem has only only one dependency:

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.1'
```

I have spent few hours and even simple form can't be sent.

Any ideas? What could be wrong?

Edit:

I tried to do a test:

```
$.get('/admin/software/111', function(data) { console.log(data) })
$.get('/admin/banners/111', function(data) { console.log(data) })
```

There are no elements with id=111. First line gives

```
404 not found
```

second one only

```
(failed)
```

It looks like server doesn't get this request. There are no logs for banner.

RESOLVED ==============

I replaced:

```
resources :banners
```

with:

```
resources :banner
```

Why this works and previous one doesn't? I have no idea.

Comment: Do you see anything in the console? Any error?

Comment: Sorry, but I have to ask. Just how similar are the controller codes? Would you mind posting a taste?

Comment: Even when I clear out controller content it doesn't work.
It looks like any route for banner resource is dennied when posting with xhr. There are no logs in rails server about this requests.

Comment: Did you include jquery_ujs ???

Comment: Yes. Of course. All other models are OK.